# How do I combine data from two tables and display them in a single column?

Tags: codeigniter, database-design, phpmyadmin

I have two views, repair and maintenance. both are a combination of three tables: repair, r_list, item; and maintenance, m_list, and item. I need to put the id of repair and the id of maintenance into a single column named ticket_id in a third table, tickets. So basically it should be like this:
[three tables plus three tables into one table combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvpyO.png)

All three tables must exist simultaneously, meaning any change in repair should affect tickets, and the same thing with maintenance. I'm using CodeIgniter, and this is my code:

**Model:**

```
    public function get_tickets_view()
        {
            $this->db->select("
                tickets.id AS id,

                repair.repair_id AS ticket_id,
                maintenance.maintenance_id AS ticket_id,

                items.item_id AS item_id,

            ");
            
            $this->db->from("tickets");
            $this->db->join("items", "tickets.item_id = items.item_id", "left");
            $this->db->join("repair", "repair.item_id = tickets.item_id", "left");
            $this->db->join("maintenance", "maintenance.item_id = tickets.item_id", "left");


            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

**Controller**

```
    public function tickets()
        {
            $data['ticket'] = $this->sample_model->get_tickets_view();

            $data['main_content'] = 'page_address';
            $this->load->view('navbar', $data);

        }
```

Despite the page displaying properly, it refuses to actually pull the items inside either of those two table views. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine arrays with

```
<?php $animals = array( "monkey","fish","ape"); $humans = array("Jim","Bob", "Josh");

array_merge($animals,$humans); 
?>
```

There are tons of array functions here:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Comment: I'm admittedly not familiar with it, and implementation examples on the Internet are unclear on where and how I should use it. Can you provide a sample?